# Adding multiple if (usertype) exceptions

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

How would one go about adding two user types to one exception?

Example: User type 1 and User type 2 can view Data Row 1.

Currently I have in source code:

```
<% if (stUSER_TYPE == "UserType1")  { %>

<asp:Literal ID="ltrMembershipExpirationDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine conditions with the OR operator ||

```
if (stUSER_TYPE == "UserType1" || stUSER_TYPE == "UserType2")
```